# how to convert duration in (milli)seconds into text in current Locale?

Tags: java

I have a number of milliseconds as a duration. I want to format it as a text in current locale. Are there any libraries that can help me?

I expect something like this:

```
long msec = 55 * 1000;
assert format(msec, Locale.ENGLISH).equals("55 sec");
assert format(msec, new Locale("ru")).equals("55 сек");
```

Comment: [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What do you mean format? (as a number/time etc.)? There is `SimpleDateFormat` and the `NumberFormat` etc.

Comment: @Andreas_D - as much as I like it too, it is *not* the answer to everything... :)

Comment: @Nim - he asked if *any* library exists - joda is one ;) - and, in opposite to Javas standard Date API, it can handle durations and periods.

Comment: @Andreas_D could you please give an example of how JodaTime may help here?

Comment: This is overkill for translating a 3 letter word, but have a look at  ResourceBundle at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in a library, which already contains all these resources (with many languages).

Answer (score 0):

You did not write how the output should look like but as for duration you can use **TimeUnit** from java.util.concurrent.

Comment: Use can the TimeUnit for conversion of milliseconds to something else (seconds, minutes,hours). As for units, you have to create some resource bundles and use them. 

You can also use org.clapper.util.text.Duration probably but you'' have to create resource bundles too.